# Laravel generate object using model factory with parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I have this model factory that generates new contact, it uses random `company_id`:

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Contact::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) 
{
    $company_id = Company::all()->random()->id;

    return [
        'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
        'lastname' => $faker->lastName,
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'company_id' => $company_id,
        'lead_id' => \App\Models\Lead::where('company_id', $company_id)->get()->random()->id,
    ];
});
```

It is ok when I use it in seeds:

```
factory(App\Models\Contact::class)->create();
```

But for testing I need somehow to pass `$company_id` to factory, create contact for concrete `company_id` (I know that I can do `->create(['company_id', $company_id])`) but this will rewrite only company_id from Contact.

When I select `lead_id`, I also need to know current `company_id`.

How to pass company_id to factory as parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use this example:

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Contact::class, function ($faker, $params) {
    $company_id = $params['company_id'];
    ....
});
```

and this to make a new object:

```
$newContact = factory(App\Models\Contact::class)->make(['company_id' => $current_company_id]);
```

Comment: That's great if you are using a parameter that is then also stored on the DB, but how about a parameter which is "just" a parameter? I tried that with `create(['par' => value])`, and promptly got a "column 'par' not found" error. Then I refactored the code a bit and managed to use a parameter that was also a column. In my case it made sense (it was a classname for a polymorphic relationship, and the factory makes objects of the type I request), but how about other cases? I could try using an existing parameter, which is then overwritten in the factory, but that sounds really hacky...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your Laravel version it will be different.

For laravel 5.1 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9245

- You will need to check if is passed manually

  ```
  // Testcase 
  $company = factory(App\Models\Company::class)->create(); 
  factory(App\Models\Contact::class)->create(['company_id' => $company->id]);

  // Factory
  $factory->define(App\Models\Contact::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker, $attribues) {

      // Manually check if id is passed 
      $company_id = (isset($attribues['company_id'])) ?: Company::all()->random()->id;

      return [
          'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
          'lastname' => $faker->lastName,
          'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
          'email' => $faker->email,
          'company_id' => $company_id,
          'lead_id' => \App\Models\Lead::where('company_id', $company_id)->get()->random()->id,
      ];
  });
  ```
- For Laravel 5.2 and above you can simply pass id
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#relationships

  ```
  // Testcase 
  $company = factory(App\Models\Company::class)->create(); 
  factory(App\Models\Contact::class)->create(['company_id' => $company->id]);

  // Factory
  $factory->define(App\Models\Contact::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker, $attribues) {

      // Manually check if id is passed 
      $company_id = (isset($attribues['company_id'])) ?: Company::all()->random()->id;

      return [
          'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
          'lastname' => $faker->lastName,
          'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
          'email' => $faker->email,
          'company_id' => function(){
               return factory(\App\Models\Company::class)->create()
           },
          'lead_id' => \App\Models\Lead::where('company_id', $company_id)->get()->random()->id,
      ];
  });
  ```

So, for your case, get your random company_id first and pass it to factory. Depends on your Larval version change the ContactModel factory. Or if you have relation that you can query, you can do it as well.

```
// If you have a relation 
$contact = factory(App\Models\Contact::class)->create(); 

$company_id = $contact->company->id;
```